# showing a cookie value on flash

Tags: flash, cookies, banner

I have a question that I cant quite start.
I have a web site that record some cookies: name, age, sex, etc.

I would like to know if it is possible to create a flash banner that display this information, like: hello [name], how are you doing today?

I was searching online and everything that I found needs something outside flash to work.

Is that a way to create a flash that can read cookie's values and show then???

Of course I am assuming that the flash will be in the same domain as the cookie.

cheers and thank you

PC

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a SharedObject. http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3sharedobject/

Comment: Arent the information on this link talking about what they call "flash cookie"????

Comment: Yes, you mentioned not wanting to use anything "outside of flash," so you can use a "Flash Cookie" (shared Object) and not have to talk with your JavaScript at all for it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have javascript to pass the values of browser cookies to flash. Typically flash banner are not allowed to have any script access to the page they are on. 
But talk to your ad vendor, they will often help implement custom functionality.

However, if you are grabbing data from a cookie your site did not set (as would likely be the case with a banner) that would probably not fly well with users, or a site's privacy policy.

Comment: thanks.I know that and both the cookie and the flash we in the same domain. Thank you :)